# Pitt's theorem and reflexivity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Does it follow from Pitt's theorem that the space of bounded operators from $\ell_2$ to $\ell_p$ ($p<2$) is actually reflexive? We have 
$$
\mathcal{B}(\ell_2, \ell_p) = \mathcal{K}(\ell_2, \ell_p)
$$ 
so by standard duality also 
$$
\mathcal{K}(\ell_2, \ell_p)^{**} =\mathcal{B}(\ell_2, \ell_p)
$$
Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

**Proof №1.** In the article [On the structre of the tensor products of $\ell_p$-spaces](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9402205.pdf) it is stated that 
$$
\ell_{p_1}\otimes_\pi\ldots\otimes_{\pi}\ell_{p_n}
$$ is reflexive if $r(p_1,\ldots,p_n):=\min\left(1,\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^{-1}\right)^{-1}>1$.

Let $q$ be conjugate to $p$, then $q>2$ and respective $r(2,q)>1$. Hence $\ell_2\otimes_\pi \ell_q$ is refexive. Note that
$$
\mathcal{K}(\ell_2,\ell_p)=\mathcal{B}(\ell_2,\ell_p)=\mathcal{B}(\ell_2,\ell_q^*)=(\ell_2\otimes_{\pi}\ell_q)^*
$$
Hence $\mathcal{K}(\ell_2,\ell_p)$ is reflexive as dual of reflexive space.

**Proof №2.** In the article [Remarks on Banach spaces of compact operators](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123679900429) theorem 2 states that if $E$ and $F$ Banach spaces one of which have approximation property then the following are equivalent

- $\mathcal{K}(E,F)$ is reflexive
- $\mathcal{B}(E,F)$ is reflexive
- $E$ and $F$ are reflexive and $\mathcal{K}(E,F)=\mathcal{B}(E,F)$

Now take $E=\ell_2$, $F=\ell_p$. They are both reflexive. Since $E$ admits Shauder basis (any orthonormal basis will fit), then it have approximation property. By Pitt's theorem $\mathcal{K}(E,F)=\mathcal{B}(E,F)$. Hence third condition of previous theorem is satisfied, so $\mathcal{K}(E,F)$ is reflexive.

**Remark** One can easily see that the last approach can give more general result: if $1<p<q<\infty$ then $\mathcal{K}(\ell_p,\ell_q)$ is reflexive.